# Converting Uncompressed TIF file to a TIF file with compression LZW and ZIP

Tags: image, zip, compression, image-compression, lzw

I used RawTherapee Application in Ubuntu OS to convert RAW file to TIF.

After that, converted that Uncompressed TIF file using ImageMagick with compressions types LZW and ZIP. Then, used ExIFTool to get the compression name. **LZW** shows correctly but ZIP shows **Adobe Deflate** as Compression Type.

Is Adobe Deflate and Zip are same? Is ZIP is a lossless compression

Is there any **proprietary issue** or anything related to Adobe name usage?
I like to go always with Open Source tools and application. Please suggest me your concerns.

Comment: ZIP compression is lossless.  Can you not just use ImageMagick to read the raw tiff and compress it.

Comment: No. I used ImageMagick to convert TIF to TIF. The thing is I used ImageMagick is to compress the TIF file and create a new TIF file. From RAW to TIF conversion I used the RawTherapee application.

Comment: My question is that you should be able to use ImageMagick to read the TIF and also to compress it to ZIP. So you should be able to avoid one step. Thus you start with RAW TIFF and compress with ZIP all within ImageMagick.

Comment: Yes That is possible. But I am getting a Pink Layered on top of the TIF when converting with ImageMagick. [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573356/pink-background-colour-in-output-tiff-when-reading-and-writing-some-tiff-images ] like this issue. So I tried Raw Therapee application to convert RAW to TIF in Raw Therapee the TIF looks same as how it was taken. I got really confused why that Pink color is shown up in Ubuntu when viewing it in the default Shotwell viewer. Thats why I used RawTherapee to convert Raw to TIF

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your tiff files from your other question about it being pink is that the tiff file is compressed with an old style JPG compression that libtiff used by ImageMagick cannot handle.

```
convert input-landscape.tiff x.tiff
```

*convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/983. convert: Inconsistent number of MCU in codestream.` OJPEGDecodeRaw' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/606.*

Comment: No. The issue is when I opened RAW image with the ShotWell viewer in Ubuntu I got the Pink Layer. When convert the RAW to TIF using ImageMagick I got the Pink layer. So, I don't think its an issue in TIF file. Because the When I open the RAW file with RawTherapee application it shows me the file as how it was taken. https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1009934.html This forum gave me an idea to use Raw Therapee since the discussion is about the layer issue

Comment: The issue in the TIFF file is that it was compressed as JPG with an older JPG compression that many tools do not understand, include ImageMagick. You need to see if the tool that creates the TIFF can use a more current JPG compression or use ZIP or LZW compression. Then ImageMagick will handle it fine. Apparently that file is **not** uncompressed TIFF which I thought you meant by RAW.

Comment: I am not sure that there would be any issue with the TIF since it converts without any Pink layer issues in Windows with Canon's Digital Photo Professional software and other software like Photoshop and Adobe CC. In Ubuntu even when using Raw Therapee it converts without any issue. I am not sure while convering in Raw Therapee it converts but in ImageMagick it creates a Pink layer. I am converting it from RAW to TIF in both ImageMagick and Raw Therapee.

Comment: The issue is the old JPG compression. Some tools such as libtiff, which Imagmagick uses, cannot read that. But other may read it fine if it has code to decompress the old JPG format